# Is there a way to generate the single dbt documentation page for a sequence of compilations with different variables passed?

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

I am new to [dbt](https://www.getdbt.com/) and have the following problem statement: for a number of subsequent compilations generate the single [documentation page](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/documentation) that will contain information for all of them.

The reason for sequence of compilations is that in my data model one [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery) [dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets-intro) serves for one customer and most of the [dbt models](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models) for each customer are nearly identical. So, one dbt model is created for all customers but how it should be compiled is controlled by a [variable](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-variables) (customer) passed:

```
dbt docs generate --var 'customer: foo'
dbt docs generate --var 'customer: bar'
```

The problem with such an approach is that despite significant reduction of code that should be written each compilation overrides the documentation page created by the previous one.

I found a [similar case](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/single-documentation-page-for-all-projects/946/7), but there the single documentation page is generated for multiple projects. One of the mentioned approaches is to merge artifacts (config, manifest) from 'target' folder that are required for documentation. This approach looks quite tricky but even despite this fact after merge there will be a set of nodes with identical names (model is the same, but only the variable passed is different) which is [currently prohibited](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/1269#issuecomment-920764492).

Has anybody handled similar task?
Thank you so much